# Adding an attribute value to a link in a jqGrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add a button inside a jqGrid column and to assign it an action related to an element of the grid. Here is my grid definition (I will only concentrate on things important for the question)

```
$("#dashboard").jqGrid({
    url: wsBaseUrl + 'xxxxxxxx',
    colNames: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'Actions'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'col1', index: 'col1', formatter: statusFormatter },
        { name: 'col2', index: 'col2', formatter: statusFormatter },
        { name: 'col3', index: 'col3', formatter: statusFormatter },
        { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 46, sortable: false, search: false,
            formatter: function () {
                var cnt = "<a class='pc_link' href='#'>Perimeter Change list</a>" +
                    "<a class='nopc_Link' href='#'>NO perimeter change </a>";
                return cnt;
            }}
    ],
    jsonReader: {
        id: "elementID"
    },
    pager: $('#dashboard_pager'),

    // ... other params omitted for brevity

    gridComplete: function () {
        $(".pc_Link").button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-folder-open" }, text: false
        });
        $(".nopc_Link").button({
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-star" }, text: false
        });
    },
    subGrid: true,

    // ... other params omitted for brevity

});
```

As you can see I have a column in my `colModel` definition that act as an Action Column: that is, I create two hyperlinks in this column that shall be binded to a `click` event and react accordingly.

After that I have a `gridComplete()` event where I plan to bind the click event.

What I need is a way to set the `rel` attribute of the hyperlink with the value of the current `rowObject` ID so I can retrieve it when making the call. Like in the following example:

```
<a class='pc_link' href='#' rel='123'>Perimeter Change list</a>
```

Is there a way to obtain this?

thanks for helping!

Comment: not sure i understood fully- you're trying to set an attribute on the anchor element which is dependent on the row data? If so- the formatter function accepts a parameter representing the row data (`rowObject`).

Comment: @sJhonny: really? I did'nt know that! If you answer this question I can set it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the formatter function accepts a parameter representing the row data (rowObject).
see [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter).